# MASM32: Display the time within the day

Tags: assembly

I need to display the time within the day and print Morning, Afternoon or Evening.

i.      Morning (4:00AM – 11:59AM)
ii.     Afternoon (12:00PM – 5:59PM)
iii.    Evening (6:00PM – 3:59AM)

I used GetTimeFormat with timeformat in 24hr. ecx actually contains 1-24 depending on the system time.

```
 invoke GetTimeFormat, 0, 0, 0, ADDR timeformat, ADDR time_buf, 50
 mov ecx, offset time_buf
 push ecx
 push ecx
 push ecx
 add ecx, eax; add length returned by GetTimeFormat      

 pop ecx
 cmp ecx, 4 
 je AM
 jg AMNN
 jl PM

 AMNN:   
 pop ecx
 cmp ecx, 12         
 jl AM
 jge NNPM

 NNPM:   
 pop ecx
 cmp ecx, 18 
 jl NN
 jge PM
```

This code always outputs the PM message. :(

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mov ecx, offset time_buf
> ```

This instruction loads the address of *time_buf* in the `ECX` register.
It's **the address itself that you compare with 4** (The 4 is supposed to be an hour indication). That explains why you always get the *PM* message.

You need to dereference like in `cmp dword [ecx], 4`.

And because *GetTimeFormat* returns **text**, you will have to compare with the character "4".

---

> ```
> add ecx, eax; add length returned by GetTimeFormat      
> pop ecx
> ```

Please verify that the addition to the `ECX` register here is not useful because of the `pop ecx` that follows immediately!

---

> ```
> push ecx
> push ecx
> push ecx
> ```

Why the 3 pushes? The `cmp` instruction does not destroy the value in `ECX`, and so you can keep using it in the several branches.

Comment: Hi! I tried your suggestion but it doesn't compile. It gives me error on the 3 lines with cmp dword[ecx], 4. Also i tried to make it a string, "4". Doesn't work either.